# JAXB - convert XML file with XSD/namespace references in it

Tags: java, jaxb

How can I convert the XML with XSD's/namespaces to an object?

I get this error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0", local:"FeatureCollection").
>   Expected elements are <{}FeatureCollection>

This is the example XML:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="7961422" numberReturned="0" timeStamp="2019-07-16T09:44:51.540Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"/>
```

My simple JAXB converter is:

```
public static Object convertXmlToObject(String xmlString, Class targetClass) {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( targetClass);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The call to this method is:

```
TargetObject to = (TargetObject) converter.convertXmlToObject( xmlString, TargetObject.class);
```

The target object is:

```
@XmlRootElement( name="FeatureCollection")
public class TargetObject {
    private long numberMatched = -1;
    private long numberReturned = -1;
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
    // ... all getters
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setNumberMatched(long numberMatched) {
        this.numberMatched = numberMatched;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setNumberReturned(long numberReturned) {
        this.numberReturned = numberReturned;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    public void setTimeStamp(LocalDateTime timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

How can I improve my code to convert the XML string to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enjoy this generic solution:

- The converter class
- A Junit Test -- showing 1 test without namespaces, but it surely works with namespaces

The converter class using XSLT to strip the namespaces. JAXB can sometimes be too literal, as you can read in many posts.

```
public class XmlToPojo {
    public static Object convertXmlToObject(String xmlString, Class targetClass) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            // Step 1 - remove namespaces
            StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            removeNamespace(xmlSource, result);
            // Step 2 - convert XML to object
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(targetClass);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(result.getWriter().toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Remove namespaces from XML

    private static String xsltNameSpaceRemover = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <xsl:output indent=\"yes\" method=\"xml\" encoding=\"utf-8\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\"/>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <!-- Stylesheet to remove all namespaces from a document -->\n" +
            "    <!-- NOTE: this will lead to attribute name clash, if an element contains\n" +
            "        two attributes with same local name but different namespace prefix -->\n" +
            "    <!-- Nodes that cannot have a namespace are copied as such -->\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <!-- template to copy elements -->\n" +
            "    <xsl:template match=\"*\">\n" +
            "        <xsl:element name=\"{local-name()}\">\n" +
            "            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@* | node()\"/>\n" +
            "        </xsl:element>\n" +
            "    </xsl:template>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <!-- template to copy attributes -->\n" +
            "    <xsl:template match=\"@*\">\n" +
            "        <xsl:attribute name=\"{local-name()}\">\n" +
            "            <xsl:value-of select=\".\"/>\n" +
            "        </xsl:attribute>\n" +
            "    </xsl:template>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->\n" +
            "    <xsl:template match=\"comment() | text() | processing-instruction()\">\n" +
            "        <xsl:copy/>\n" +
            "    </xsl:template>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</xsl:stylesheet>";

    private static void removeNamespace(Source xmlSource, Result xmlOutput) throws TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltNameSpaceRemover));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, xmlOutput);
    }
}
```

A simple Junit test:

```
public class XmlToPojoTest {
    @Test
    public void testBasic() {
        String xmlString = "<employee>" +
                "    <department>" +
                "        <id>101</id>" +
                "        <name>IT-ABC</name>" +
                "    </department>" +
                "    <firstName>JJ</firstName>" +
                "    <id>1</id>" +
                "    <lastName>JoHo</lastName>" +
                "</employee>";
        XmlToPojo xmlToPojo = new XmlToPojo();
        Employee emp = (Employee) xmlToPojo.convertXmlToObject(xmlString, Employee.class);
        assertEquals("JJ", emp.getFirstName());
        assertEquals("IT-ABC", emp.getDepartment().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you!